# No reaction from eventListener in Backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, listener

I've created a new backbone application and i wonder how i can update my view when a model changes if I uses my current way of using backbone. I already wrote a listenTo function but i got no errors and don't know if it updates or not. Also i want to try to sort. Example sort on title and sort on category buttons that rerender the view in de right order.

This is my code, thanks for the help!

```
var url;
var Artikel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'api/items.json',
  defaults: {
        id: '',
        titel: 'Titel niet opgegeven',
        url_titel: 'unieke sleutel urltitel',
        img_path: 'geen image toegevoegd',
        commentaar: 'Commentaar niet opgegeven',
        categorie: 'Categorie niet opgegeven',
        waardering: 0,
        artikel: 'Artikel niet opgegeven'
    },
    initialize: function(){

      if(!this.get('description')){
        var lazy = 'This user was too lazy too add a description';
        this.set('description', lazy);
      }
    }
});


 var Artikels = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Artikel,
   sortAttribute: "categorie",
   sortDirection: 1,

   sortArtikels: function (attr) {
      this.sortAttribute = attr;
      this.sort();
   },

   comparator: function(a, b) {
      var a = a.get(this.sortAttribute),
          b = b.get(this.sortAttribute);

      if (a == b) return 0;

      if (this.sortDirection == 1) {
         return a > b ? 1 : -1;
      } else {
         return a < b ? 1 : -1;
      }
   },
  url: 'api/items.json'
});


var ArtikelLijst = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',

  initialize: function(){

    this.listenTo(artikel, 'all', this.render); //how do i test this, is this correct? (no errors)

  },
  render: function(){
    this.render;

    var that = this;
    var artikels = new Artikels();

    artikels.fetch({
      success:function(artikels){

        artikels.toJSON();
        var template = _.template($('#artikel-overzicht-template').html(), {artikels: artikels.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    });
  }
});

var artikelLijst


var ArtikelDetail = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',

  // events:{
  //   'submit .form' : 'saveArtikel'
  // },
  // saveArtikel: function (ev){

  //   var artikelDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
  //   var artikel = new Artikels();

  //   artikel.save(artikelDetails, {
  //     succes: function(artikel){
  //       router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
  //     }
  //     })
  //     return false;

  // },
  render: function(options){

    var that = this;
    var artikel = new Artikels();
    url = options.id;
    artikel.fetch({
      success: function(artikel,options)
      {
        var vindartikel = artikel.where({url_titel: url});
        var artikelcol = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model:Artikels
        });
        var specifiekArtikel = new artikelcol(vindartikel);
        var template = _.template($('#detail-edit-template').html(),{specifiekArtikel:specifiekArtikel.models});
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
     });

  }
});


var artikel = new Artikels();
var artikelLijst = new ArtikelLijst({model: Artikels});
var artikelDetail = new ArtikelDetail();


console.log(artikel); // this gives empty array? how can i test if the view updates when the model is changed?

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
      "": "home",
      "detail/:id": "detail"
    },

    home: function() {
      artikelLijst.render();
    },

    detail: function(id) {
        artikelDetail.render({id: id});
    }

  });

//init router
var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

I tried different aproches but still didn't got it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artikel variable in this line :

```
this.listenTo(artikel, 'all', this.render);
```

refers to any variable, is it a global var ?

Try to do like this :

```
this.model.bind('change', this.render)
```

Comment: how do i check if that works?
artikel is var artikel = new Artikels();

Comment: Ok i fixed it thanks to you, with underscore js it works:

_.bindAll(this, "render");
this.model.bind('change', this.render);

Comment: Ok good, but I have some enhancements you can apply to your code : 1- you shouldn't use underscore bindAll method because when you use this.model.bind() it uses the underscore's method under the hood. 2- you shouldn't call the model/collection fetch method inside the view render. 3- in the router you should call model.fetch() rather than view.render() and when the model is changed it will trigger the view rendering because of the bind you did in the view initialize method.